# Error with JSON results from a cfc file for JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to use JQUERY with Coldfusion. I would like to retrieve results from a database in JSON format from a function in a cfc file. I need to create the json manually with several queries:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction name="getTransports" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="false">
        <cfargument name="CITY_TO" type="string" required="yes">  
        <cfargument name="CITY_FROM" type="string" required="yes"> 

        <cfquery name ="transport" datasource="#application.datasource#">
        <!---Query Transports--->
            select * from TRANSPORTS
        </cfquery>

        <cfset transports = arrayNew(1)>

        <cfloop from="1" to="#transport.recordcount#" index="i">   

            <cfquery name="defined_transport" datasource="#application.datasource#">
                select * from TABLE_FRAIS 
                where CITY_TO = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.CITY_TO#">
                and CITY_FROM = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.CITY_FROM#">
                and CTRP_ST_CODE = '#transport.TRANSPORT_CODE#' 
            </cfquery>

            <cfif defined_transport.recordCount eq 0>
                <cfset transport_value = "#transport.TRANSPORT_NAME# (not defined)">
            <cfelse>  
                <cfset transport_value = "#transport.TRANSPORT_NAME#">
            </cfif>

            <cfset transpVO = structNew() />

            <cfset transpVO['ID']= #transport.TRANSPORT_CODE# />            
            <cfset transpVO['VALUE']= #transport_value# />      
            <cfset transports[i] = transpVO />
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn transports>       

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

When I retrieve results in my JQUERY script, I obtain a string JSON:

```
[ { "ID" : "APEX",
    "VALUE" : "Apex (not defined)"
  },
  { "ID" : "AVI",
    "VALUE" : "Plane (not defined)"
  },
  { "ID" : "TRAIN 1",
    "VALUE" : "Train 1st class"
  },
  { "ID" : "VOIT",
    "VALUE" : "Car"
  },
  { "ID" : "ZERO",
    "VALUE" : "Cost 0 (not defined)"
  }
]
```

**EDIT:**

Here my JQUERY script for retrieving data thanks to Coldfusion:

```
$().ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type:   'GET',
        url:    'transports.cfc',
        data: {
            method:     'getTransports',
            CITY_TO:    'LUX',
            CITY_FROM:  'UWP'
        },
        dataType: "application/json",  //this is important      responsetype:'JSON',

        success: function(result) {
            var select = $("##transp");
            select.empty();
            select.append(
                new Option('Select transport', '-1')
            );
            console.log(result); // display the JSON
            console.log(result.length); // displays 252
        },
        error: function(xhr, message) {
            alert('ajax request failed');
            console.log(xhr, message);
        }
     });
});
```

The resultats are displayed in the console, mais if I do not know how to populate the drop down. I tried to add that:

```
        select.append(
            new Option(item.ID, item.VALUE)
        );
```

I obtain 252 rows in the drop down without text.

But I'm trying to use it to populate a drop down list, but I cannot do it.

Could you tell me if my coldfusion function and my JSON results are ok?

Regards,

Comment: Your JSON result seems ok (it is valid in http://jsonlint.com/). Can't the issue occurs when you try to populate the dropdown list? You don't explain why you can't do it.

Comment: I add the JQUERY code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue comes from your script. You should try to add the option one at a time using a loop :

```
var select = $("#transp");
select.empty();
select.append(
    new Option('Select transport', '-1')
);
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    select.append(
      new Option(result[i].ID, result[i].VALUE)
    );
}
```

Here a working snippet : http://jsfiddle.net/odp3dve8/1/

```js
//oResult simulates the AJAX result :
var oResult = [ { "ID" : "APEX",
    "VALUE" : "Apex (not defined)"
  },
  { "ID" : "AVI",
    "VALUE" : "Plane (not defined)"
  },
  { "ID" : "TRAIN 1",
    "VALUE" : "Train 1st class"
  },
  { "ID" : "VOIT",
    "VALUE" : "Car"
  },
  { "ID" : "ZERO",
    "VALUE" : "Cost 0 (not defined)"
  }
];


var select = $("#transp");
select.empty();
select.append(
    new Option('Select transport', '-1')
);
//Loop on each element of the JSON result and add each option.
for(var i=0; i<oResult.length; i++){
    select.append(
      new Option(oResult[i].ID, oResult[i].VALUE)
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="transp">
    <option value="1">Fake option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Fake option 2</option>
</select>
```

---

EDIT.
For the string/json issue, you can try to update your request parameters "headers" and "datatype" :

```
$.ajax({
    type:   'GET',
    url:    'transports.cfc',
    data: { ... },

    headers: {'Accept': "application/json"},
    dataType: "json",


    success: function(result) { ... }
    error: function(result) { ... }
});
```

And if that doesn't work, you may be interested by this article: 
http://blog.tcs.de/coldfusion-query-to-javascript-object/

Comment: Apparently your script works, but in my code it doesn't work. I'm sure that it's a problem of content-type. In jquery the results JSON are considered as string and that's why console.log(result.length) displays 252... In firebug I can see in the XHR request : header response - content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8. Do you know how to solve that??

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same when I add headers: {'Accept': "application/json"},...if I replace  dataType: "application/json", by dataType: "json" I go directly in error function.

Comment: Then your Coldfusion response is most likely not in JSON despite the attribute "returnformat='JSON'". I won't be able to help you more as my cfc knowledge isn't great.

Comment: And if you don't find out, you can still use parseJSON() to convert the string into a JSON object. This is not the best solution, but it should work. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Hi, It's still the same issue. but in fact when I try to do a console.log(result), I have seen that: 

<!-- 
LNG_CD = 'ENG'
-->

[{"VALUE":"Apex (not defined)","ID":"APEX"},{"VALUE":"Plane (not defined)","ID":"AVI"},{"VALUE":"Train 1st class","ID":"TRAIN 1"},{"VALUE":"Car","ID":"VOIT"},{"VALUE":"Cost 0 (not defined)","ID":"ZERO"}] Do you know <!-- 
LNG_CD = 'ENG' ???
-->